# Missing properties in the occurrences of recurring events when using delta function

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

i'm trying to fetch the list of all modified Outlook event instances in a certain time period using Microsoft Graph and the delta funcion.

When i call the the following endpoint:

> /users/{userId}/calendars/{calendarId}/calendarView/delta?startDateTime={start}&endDateTime={end}

i get the list of all normal events with all their properties correctly set. But if there are recurring events, their occurrences only have these properties: @odata.type, @odata.etag, seriesMasterId, type, id, start, end.

The docs don't say anything about this. Should i read all the other properties from the master event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that's correct. Any property not set on the occurrence should be interpreted as having the same value as the master.